# How can I edit codes like social media link or remove something from all of my web pages in notepad++ automatically?

Tags: html

I am working on a website in which there are around 10 pages so if i have to add or delete some code I have to manually remove it from all of my pages manually, is there a way in which I enter a code and it changes in all the pages as I want

I am using toolbucket plugin but it is not that useful

Comment: Have you tried the built-in Search and replace function with the button to do it in every open file?

Comment: @Nekomajin42 Yes I have but it deos not works when i have to edit many lines of code

Comment: Have you tried using regex?